# Regarding WebServiceDiscriptionLanguage: exception: ; nested exception is: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, axis, wsdl2java

I am attaching my java file, which is giving me the following error:

```
exception: ; nested exception is: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0 Size: 0
```

---

```
/**
 * CreateINCIDENTCRMType.java
 *
 * This file was auto-generated from WSDL
 * by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.
 */

package com.ibm.www.maximo;

public class CreateINCIDENTCRMType  implements java.io.Serializable {
  //  private com.ibm.www.maximo.INCIDENTCRM_INCIDENTType[] INCIDENTCRMSet;

private java.util.Calendar creationDateTime;  // attribute

private java.lang.String baseLanguage;  // attribute

private java.lang.String transLanguage;  // attribute

private java.lang.String messageID;  // attribute

private java.lang.String maximoVersion;  // attribute

public CreateINCIDENTCRMType() {
}

public CreateINCIDENTCRMType(
       com.ibm.www.maximo.INCIDENTCRM_INCIDENTType[] INCIDENTCRMSet,
       java.util.Calendar creationDateTime,
       java.lang.String baseLanguage,
       java.lang.String transLanguage,
       java.lang.String messageID,
       java.lang.String maximoVersion) {
    //   this.INCIDENTCRMSet = INCIDENTCRMSet;
       this.creationDateTime = creationDateTime;
       this.baseLanguage = baseLanguage;
       this.transLanguage = transLanguage;
       this.messageID = messageID;
       this.maximoVersion = maximoVersion;
}


/**
 * Gets the INCIDENTCRMSet value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @return INCIDENTCRMSet
 */
/*public com.ibm.www.maximo.INCIDENTCRM_INCIDENTType[] getINCIDENTCRMSet() {
    return INCIDENTCRMSet;
}*/


/**
 * Sets the INCIDENTCRMSet value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @param INCIDENTCRMSet
 */
/*public void setINCIDENTCRMSet(com.ibm.www.maximo.INCIDENTCRM_INCIDENTType[] INCIDENTCRMSet) {
    this.INCIDENTCRMSet = INCIDENTCRMSet;
}*/


/**
 * Gets the creationDateTime value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @return creationDateTime
 */
public java.util.Calendar getCreationDateTime() {
    return creationDateTime;
}


/**
 * Sets the creationDateTime value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @param creationDateTime
 */
public void setCreationDateTime(java.util.Calendar creationDateTime) {
    this.creationDateTime = creationDateTime;
}


/**
 * Gets the baseLanguage value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @return baseLanguage
 */
public java.lang.String getBaseLanguage() {
    return baseLanguage;
}


/**
 * Sets the baseLanguage value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @param baseLanguage
 */
public void setBaseLanguage(java.lang.String baseLanguage) {
    this.baseLanguage = baseLanguage;
}


/**
 * Gets the transLanguage value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @return transLanguage
 */
public java.lang.String getTransLanguage() {
    return transLanguage;
}


/**
 * Sets the transLanguage value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @param transLanguage
 */
public void setTransLanguage(java.lang.String transLanguage) {
    this.transLanguage = transLanguage;
}


/**
 * Gets the messageID value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @return messageID
 */
public java.lang.String getMessageID() {
    return messageID;
}


/**
 * Sets the messageID value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @param messageID
 */
public void setMessageID(java.lang.String messageID) {
    this.messageID = messageID;
}


/**
 * Gets the maximoVersion value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @return maximoVersion
 */
public java.lang.String getMaximoVersion() {
    return maximoVersion;
}


/**
 * Sets the maximoVersion value for this CreateINCIDENTCRMType.
 * 
 * @param maximoVersion
 */
public void setMaximoVersion(java.lang.String maximoVersion) {
    this.maximoVersion = maximoVersion;
}

private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null;
public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof CreateINCIDENTCRMType)) return false;
    CreateINCIDENTCRMType other = (CreateINCIDENTCRMType) obj;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (__equalsCalc != null) {
        return (__equalsCalc == obj);
    }
    __equalsCalc = obj;
    boolean _equals;
    _equals = true && 
        /*((this.INCIDENTCRMSet==null && other.getINCIDENTCRMSet()==null) || 
         (this.INCIDENTCRMSet!=null &&
          java.util.Arrays.equals(this.INCIDENTCRMSet, other.getINCIDENTCRMSet()))) &&*/
        ((this.creationDateTime==null && other.getCreationDateTime()==null) || 
         (this.creationDateTime!=null &&
          this.creationDateTime.equals(other.getCreationDateTime()))) &&
        ((this.baseLanguage==null && other.getBaseLanguage()==null) || 
         (this.baseLanguage!=null &&
          this.baseLanguage.equals(other.getBaseLanguage()))) &&
        ((this.transLanguage==null && other.getTransLanguage()==null) || 
         (this.transLanguage!=null &&
          this.transLanguage.equals(other.getTransLanguage()))) &&
        ((this.messageID==null && other.getMessageID()==null) || 
         (this.messageID!=null &&
          this.messageID.equals(other.getMessageID()))) &&
        ((this.maximoVersion==null && other.getMaximoVersion()==null) || 
         (this.maximoVersion!=null &&
          this.maximoVersion.equals(other.getMaximoVersion())));
    __equalsCalc = null;
    return _equals;
}

private boolean __hashCodeCalc = false;
public synchronized int hashCode() {
    if (__hashCodeCalc) {
        return 0;
    }
    __hashCodeCalc = true;
    int _hashCode = 1;
   /* if (getINCIDENTCRMSet() != null) {
        for (int i=0;
             i<java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(getINCIDENTCRMSet());
             i++) {
            java.lang.Object obj = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(getINCIDENTCRMSet(), i);
            if (obj != null &&
                !obj.getClass().isArray()) {
                _hashCode += obj.hashCode();
            }
        }
    }*/
    if (getCreationDateTime() != null) {
        _hashCode += getCreationDateTime().hashCode();
    }
    if (getBaseLanguage() != null) {
        _hashCode += getBaseLanguage().hashCode();
    }
    if (getTransLanguage() != null) {
        _hashCode += getTransLanguage().hashCode();
    }
    if (getMessageID() != null) {
        _hashCode += getMessageID().hashCode();
    }
    if (getMaximoVersion() != null) {
        _hashCode += getMaximoVersion().hashCode();
    }
    __hashCodeCalc = false;
    return _hashCode;
}

// Type metadata
private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
    new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(CreateINCIDENTCRMType.class, true);

static {
    typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.ibm.com/maximo", "CreateINCIDENTCRMType"));
    org.apache.axis.description.AttributeDesc attrField = new org.apache.axis.description.AttributeDesc();
    attrField.setFieldName("creationDateTime");
    attrField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "creationDateTime"));
    attrField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "dateTime"));
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(attrField);
    attrField = new org.apache.axis.description.AttributeDesc();
    attrField.setFieldName("baseLanguage");
    attrField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "baseLanguage"));
    attrField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(attrField);
    attrField = new org.apache.axis.description.AttributeDesc();
    attrField.setFieldName("transLanguage");
    attrField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "transLanguage"));
    attrField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(attrField);
    attrField = new org.apache.axis.description.AttributeDesc();
    attrField.setFieldName("messageID");
    attrField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "messageID"));
    attrField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(attrField);
    attrField = new org.apache.axis.description.AttributeDesc();
    attrField.setFieldName("maximoVersion");
    attrField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "maximoVersion"));
    attrField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.ibm.com/maximo", "MaximoVersionType"));
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(attrField);
    org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
    elemField.setFieldName("INCIDENTCRMSet");
    elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.ibm.com/maximo", "INCIDENTCRMSet"));
    elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.ibm.com/maximo", "INCIDENTCRMSetType"));
    elemField.setNillable(false);
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
}

/**
 * Return type metadata object
 */
public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
    return typeDesc;
}

/**
 * Get Custom Serializer
 */
public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
       java.lang.String mechType, 
       java.lang.Class _javaType,  
       javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
    return 
      new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
        _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
}

/**
 * Get Custom Deserializer
 */
public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
       java.lang.String mechType, 
       java.lang.Class _javaType,  
       javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
    return 
      new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
        _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
}

}
```

Comment: You probably should be a little more specific with your question. Like what exactly produces the error, instead of just pasting whole source.

Answer (score 0):

You provided auto-generated code file.

This probably means that either:

- your wsdl file is wrong
- you're trying so send an invalid message to
  the server